# In Kubuntu 15.04, how do I switch the K-menu back to classic style?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, kde

I've updated to Kubuntu 15.04.  Previously, the K-menu in Plasma could be switched to classic style by [right-clicking and selecting Switch to classic style](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff).  In Kubuntu 15.04, this appears to be no longer available.

In Kubuntu 15.04, how do I switch the K menu back to classic style?

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood it correctly, you are looking for the "Application Menu" applet. Right click on the bottom bar then click on Panel Options - Add widgets and look for Applications Menu.